# Доступ к файлам UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

Как в UWP получить доступ к чтению и записи того или иного файла?
Есть ли стандартное окно диалога сохранения и записи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Guidelines for file pickers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465182.aspx):

- [FileOpenPicker class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.aspx) — открытие файла
- [FileSavePicker class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker.aspx) — сохранение файла
- [FolderPicker class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx) — выбор папки

[Save a file with a picker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-save-a-file-with-a-picker) — статья про сохранение.